# Editar texto do Button FXML

Tags: java, javafx

Não consigo mudar o texto do botão criado no FXML. Mesmo que eu coloque dentro do `initialize(... butao.setText("...");` ele não muda.

O que faço?

---

PersonController, intializable:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1){...

    adicionareditarnovadivida.getItems().addAll("Adicionar","Editar","Nova Divida","Imprimir Carnê");
    adicionareditarnovadivida.getSelectionModel().select(0);
...}
```

PersonController, Método do ComboBox:

```
@FXML
private void adednd(ActionEvent event){
    String saf = adicionareditarnovadivida.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().get();
    System.out.println(saf);
    switch(saf){
    case"Adicionar":
        adicionar.setText("Adicionar");
        imprime.setDisable(true);
        clientes.setDisable(true);
        rg.setDisable(false);
        cpf.setDisable(false);
        endereco.setDisable(false);
        break;
    case "Editar":
        adicionar.setText("Editar");
        imprime.setDisable(true);
        clientes.setDisable(false);
        rg.setDisable(true);
        cpf.setDisable(true);
        break;
    case "Nova Divida":
        adicionar.setText("Nova Divida");
        imprime.setDisable(true);
        clientes.setDisable(false);
        rg.setDisable(true);
        cpf.setDisable(true);
        endereco.setDisable(true);
        break;
    case "Imprimir Carnê":
        imprime.setDisable(false);
        clientes.setDisable(false);
        break;
    default:
        SI.AlertDialog(stage, "Erro Desconhecido.", AlertType.ERROR);
    }
}
```

PersonController, Método do Botão:

```
 @FXML  
 private void Adicionar(ActionEvent event) { ...
                switch(adicionar.getText()){
                    case "Adicionar":
                        TextFieldMascaras.adicionar(nome, divida, pagamento,compradata, vencimento, cpf, rg,telefone, endereco, produtos,stage,carne.getText());
                        break;
                    case "Editar":
                        TextFieldMascaras.editar(nome, divida, pagamento, compradata, vencimento, carne.getText(), stage,produtos);
                        break;
                    case "Nova Divida":
                        TextFieldMascaras.editar(nome, divida, pagamento, compradata, vencimento, carne.getText(), stage, produtos);
                        break;
                    case "Imprimir Carnê":
                        TextFieldMascaras.Imprimir(nome, divida, pagamento, compradata, vencimento, carne.getText(), stage, produtos);
                        break;
                    default:
                        SI.AlertDialog(stage, "Erro Deconhecido!!", AlertType.ERROR);
                    }
    ...}
```

O que está errado?

---

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1828305.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/lucas/site/Sistema%20Rose%20Banco%20de%20Dados/bin/pc/Main_m1.fxml:7

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at pc.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:16)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$54/8684414.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/18503843.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/12676431.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/2180324.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/3326003.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.layout.Pane cannot be cast to javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane
    at pc.PersonController.<init>(PersonController.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
Exception running application pc.MainApp
```

Botão:

```
    private Button adicionar = (Button) getFXMLField((AnchorPane)pane, "Adicionar");
```

---

E o MainApp:

```
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

     @Override
     public void start(Stage palco) throws Exception {
         URL arquivoFXML = getClass().getResource("Main_m1.fxml");
         Parent fxmlParent = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(arquivoFXML);
         palco.setScene(new Scene(fxmlParent));
         palco.setTitle("Contas");
         palco.show();
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(); 
     }

}
```

Comment: Como assim inicializar? Em um construtor? Coloque o código completo e/ou detalhe melhor qual é a sua dúvida.

Comment: Eu fiz um exemplo para não ter que colocar aqui muito código, mas o exemplo funcionou e agora estou vendo o que está errado. Caso não encontre eu posto o código.

Comment: Postei o código nas vezes em que aparece o botão, E me desculpe por não ter falado do ComboBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu tive este mesmo problema para carregar um arquivo properties ao abrir a tela, não sei se é a melhor forma de se resolver, mas segue o código:

```
private Node getFXMLField(AnchorPane ap, String fxid) {
    ObservableList<Node> fxmlFields = ap.getChildrenUnmodifiable();
    for (Node field : fxmlFields) {
        if(field.getId().equals(fxid)){
            return field;
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalStateException("Campo " + fxid + "não existente");
}
```

Com o Node você pode realizar o cast para qualquer componente do javafx e então setar os valores que quiser.

Um exemplo:

```
Button button1 = (Button) getFXMLField(formPai, "nome do botão");
button1.setText("xanana");
```

Comment: Como eu uso isso, pode explicar? Obrigado por Responder.

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo de utilização na resposta, se tiver mais alguma dúvida pode perguntar

Comment: Deu um novo erro. Editei a pergunta com o novo erro.

Comment: Mudei de AnchorPane para Pane e da outro erro: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Campo Adicionarnão existente`

Comment: No FXML você definiu a propriedade fxid do botão como Adicionar?

Comment: Como faz isso? Eu não usava FXML antes, então fica difícil.

Comment: No arquivo FXML voce tem que adicionar a propriedade fx.id exemplo:
<Button fx:id="Adicionar" .../>

Comment: Eu estou usando o Scene Builder e java fiz isso fx:id="Adicionar"

Comment: Tens como postar o código aonde você carrega o FXML?

Comment: Verifique se está passando para o metodo getFXMLField o pane que contem o botão. Verifique também o case do fx.id

Comment: O fx.id está certo, mas não sei se o pane contem o Botão, mas se tento adiciona-lo da o mesmo erro. Não sei o que está acontecendo mas o as as outras ações que o `switch` do `ComboBox`( que são alguns `setDisable(false)` em alguns campos TextField) funcionam e até outro botão muda, mas esse não.

Comment: Ocorre algum erro quando você utiliza o setText?

Comment: Não ele só não faz nada.

Comment: Consegui achar o erro, é um erro tão iniciante que eu não percebi, o `fx.id="Adicionar"` com "A" maiúsculo e no botão estava `@FXML private Button adicionar`, não sei como eu não percebi isso, Mas obrigado por responder.